# BreezeJS - How remove a navigational property from its parent?

Tags: javascript, entity-framework, breeze

Assuming we have a "parent" entity "Customer", a child entity "Order", and we are in the context of the child entity, how would I "detach" the Order from the Customer, without deleting the Order?  Essentially what I would do in SQL is:

```
update Order set CustomerId = NULL;
```

My remove command function looks something like this:

```
function remove(order) {
  // I've tried the following -
  // order.CustomerId(null);
  // order.Customer(null);
  // order.Customer.remove(order);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several ways depending on whether you are working with a scalar or nonscalar navigation property. In general, you can "sever" the relationship from either side.

From the 'child' or dependent side ( or the parent if a 1-1 relation).

1) Setting the scalar navigation property directly to null ( if nullable)

```
 child.parent = null;
```

2) Setting the foreign key to null

```
 child.parentID = null;
```

3) From the 'parent' or principal side ( if non scalar) and if you are dealing with a nonscalar navigation property i.e. something like parent.children, then you can remove the child from the 'children' array via 'splice'.

```
 var ix = parent.children.indexOf(child);
 parent.children.splice(ix, 1);
```

In each of these cases Breeze is aware of the change and performs the inverse operation on the other side of the relationship.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Wouldn't that navigation property still be marked as loaded though? How could one remove a navigation property from an entity and ensure that if some other component in the app calls entity.loadNavigationProperty('name') that the navigation property actually gets loaded again (i.e. remove the navigation property and restore its state to 'unloaded')